# How do I insert data by selecting some values from another table

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005

I need to insert data by selecting some part of the values needed base on the supplied values from the user.

In a scenerio, the client will provide `staff_name, customer_name`, and `product_name`. The `INSERT` will look up the necessary data from other tables to pull the corresponding ids.

This is what I currently have

```
INSERT INTO [Order](product_id, 
                    customer_id, 
                    staff_id, 
                    vehicle_regno, 
                    order_details, 
                    total_price, 
                    order_date)
     SELECT     
         stock.id, 
         customers.id AS Expr1, 
         Staff.id AS Expr2, 
         @vehicle_regno AS Expr3, 
         @order_details AS Expr4, 
         @total_price AS Expr5, 
         @order_date AS Expr6
     FROM         
         stock 
     CROSS JOIN
         customers CROSS 
     JOIN
         Staff
     WHERE     
         (stock.name = @stock_name) 
         AND (customers.name = @customers_name) 
         AND (Staff.name = @staff_name)
```

but it does not insert any record

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, first step would be: run the `SELECT` on its own - does it return anything?? What I'm most concerned about: you're joining the `Staff` table but not providing any JOIN condition.... that'll end up being a cartesian product - is that what you really want??? Also: a CROSS JOIN to Customer - really?? Isn't there any connection between Stock and Customer?? Seems you're joining together too much stuff, with too little join conditions (for my taste).....

Comment: Seeing that you already have four SQL variables for your insert - why couldn't you also determine the proper `stockId`, `customerId` and `staff.id` with statement before your `INSERT`?? I'm assuming you want to have one each - right??

Comment: @UmutDerbentoğlu this is what the query designer is giving me in visual studio

Comment: @marc_s to your first question, its not possible to execute this alone, as this select statement is tied to the insert statement

Comment: just **comment out** the `INSERT INTO.....` part ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have two separate queries here, which can be tested separately.

I mean, why don't you test this part first:

```
SELECT     
     stock.id, 
     customers.id AS Expr1, 
     Staff.id AS Expr2, 
     @vehicle_regno AS Expr3, 
     @order_details AS Expr4, 
     @total_price AS Expr5, 
     @order_date AS Expr6
 FROM         
     stock 
 CROSS JOIN
     customers CROSS 
 JOIN
     Staff
 WHERE     
     (stock.name = @stock_name) 
     AND (customers.name = @customers_name) 
     AND (Staff.name = @staff_name)
```

And see if there are any data returned.

Comment: its not possible to execute this alone, as this select statement is tied to the insert statement

Comment: What if you remove extra parameters ('@vehicle_regno', '@order_details', '@total_price' and '@order_date') from your select - can you see any data when executing the select query "alone"?

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution lies in simplifying it. Here's what I would suggest,

1. Run your select query and confirm if it's returning results.
2. If confirmed, write a stored procedure in which,

a) Run Select query and set result in variables.

b) Execute the Insert statements with given variables.

Comment: can you give me and example of this?